# why upsertedId is null in express put method with react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

**I'm trying to update or insert data to my MongoDB database but it returns wrong**

```
async function run() {
  try {
    const userCollection = client.db("doctor-portal").collection("users");
    app.put("/user", async (req, res) => {
      const filter = { email: "sabbir195661@gmail.com" };
      const updateDoc = {
        $set: {email: "mukit",},
      };
      const options = { upsurt: true };
      const result = await userCollection.updateOne(filter, updateDoc, options);
      console.log(result);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Something went wrong: ${err}`);
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

**Here is the console output**

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 0
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. I have mistaken in 'upsert' speeling